# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

I'm trying to assign a cookie value to a variable, but receiving an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined

I've tried `var name = Cookies.get('name');` but I still get the same error. [This documentation](http://code.iamkate.com/javascript/using-cookies/) also states to use the above approach.

I then assumed that the cookie value must be undefined when executing this script, so decided to check the cookie before trying to assign it to a var, like this:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (Cookies.get('name')) {
      var name = Cookies.get('name');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

... But still seeing the same error. Ideas?

Comment: The error means you haven't downloaded and included the `cookies.js` library in your page correctly.

Comment: Also `var name = Cookies.get('name') || "";`

Comment: You can use some other functions other than this library, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.

Comment: @NicolaeMaties not a recommended resource. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.1/js.cookie.min.js"></script>` - [documentation](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

There might be your script is loading before the cookies API is not fully loaded in the browser so that will give error.

Use the following and let me know if it works for you:

```
function loadJs(id, url = null, inlineScript = null, callback){
    var e = document.createElement('script');

    if (url) 
        e.src = url;

    if (inlineScript)
        e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inlineScript));

    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.id = id;
    e.defer = true;
    e.addEventListener('load', callback);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
}


loadJs("cookies-api","https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.1/js.cookie.min.js", null, function(){
    if (Cookies.get('name')) {
        var name = Cookies.get('name');
    }
})
```